# Binding List to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, bind

I have a list of credit card objects.  The credit card class is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Client
{
    public class CreditCard
    {
        public String A_Number;
        public String A_Name;
        public String A_Type;
        public String A_Owner_Type;
        public String Bank_City;
        public String Bank_State;
        public String Bank_ZIP;
        public String Balance;
        public String C_Username;

        public CreditCard()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

In another class, I am trying to bind the list to a grid view as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<CreditCard> list = (List<CreditCard>)Session["list"];
            GridView_List.DataSource = list;
            GridView_List.DataBind();
        }
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
The data source for GridView with id 'GridView_List' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content.
```

What is the problem?  I checked that the list actually contains data so I don't know why it won't work?  How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Can you please post ASPX content of GridView_List control? Look like GridView is trying to access a column which does not exist in your CreditCard object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must use public properties for DataBinding. Update your class as follows:

```
  public class CreditCard
    {
        public String A_Number { get; set; }
        public String A_Name { get; set; }
        public String A_Type { get; set; }
        public String A_Owner_Type { get; set; }
        public String Bank_City { get; set; }
        public String Bank_State { get; set; }
        public String Bank_ZIP { get; set; }
        public String Balance { get; set; }
        public String C_Username { get; set; }

        public CreditCard() { }
    }
```

Comment: I'm doing this and still have the same problem.

Comment: @Marnee post your XAML and code in another SO question so that we can help. There's no way for us to know what you're actually doing.

Comment: Thank you.  I just realized I am dumb.  I forgot to put the public access modifier in front of my properties.  Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

You have defined your `CreditCard` as an object with fields. Data binding can only be done with properties. So, you need to do something like this for all fields:

```
public String A_Number { get; set; }
```