# Search repeated elements List type Tuple

Tags: c#, list, tuples, element, repeat

I searched for information on how to perform a search for repeating elements from a List type tuple in C # but I can not do what I want, here I leave the code that more or less resembles what i want to get:

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> listadoDuplicadas;
listadoDuplicadas = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < listadoPlantillas.Count; i++)
    {
           listadoPlantillas.Any(valor => valor.Item2.Contains(listadoPlantillas[i].Item2));

    if (Match)
    {
        listadoDuplicadas.Add(listadoPlantillas[i]);
    }
}
```

the listadoPlantillas object already contains all the information where you want to perform the search of repeated elements of the "Column 2", ie just want to know if there is repeated information of that particular column, which carries the code I put it find that when any value is out of the cycle starts again and the values that will add me to listadoDuplicadas object are exactly the same as listadoPlantillas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With LINQ:

```
        List<Tuple<int, string>> listadoPlantillas;
        listadoPlantillas = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
        listadoPlantillas.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(1, "Duplicate"));
        listadoPlantillas.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(2, "Unique"));
        listadoPlantillas.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(3, "Duplicate"));


        var listadoDuplicadas = from c in listadoPlantillas
                                join c2 in listadoPlantillas on c.Item2 equals c2.Item2
                                where c != c2
                                select c;
```

This will list all duplicate items by .Item2 and put them in listadoDuplicadas

Comment: Thanks friend !!!

and I have repeated items! but now (sorry for my ignorance) as I can dump the repeated elements to a grid (eg. gridView.DataSouce = listadoDuplicadas. ####)

again thank you very much for your help!

Comment: ready and I could solve !!!     gdResultado.DataSource = listadoDuplicadas.ToList();

Comment: @elnapster : Great! You might want to create and use a tiny simple class for your items instead of a Tuple<int, string>, it would be cleaner code. This shows a simple example to bind data in a list : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020987/binding-list-to-gridview