# reading a text document with rows and columns into a datatable, then bind the data table to a gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

i have a text document that looks like this:

```
string string string string string
string string string string string
string string string string string
string string string string string
string string string string string
```

the goal is to get this information into a gridview. and display it in an windows form app.

so far i've only been able to get the info into a 2d array by doing the following:

```
string input = File.ReadAllText("path to the file");

//counters
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

//initialize array
string[,] result = new string[5, 5];

//loop
foreach (var row in input.Split('\n'))
{
    j = 0;
    foreach (var column in row.Trim().Split(' '))
    {
        result[i, j] = column.Trim();
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

what is the best way to get this into a gridview?

Comment: Instead of using two dimensional array you should store this data in an array of some entities. Create a class which represents one line of data, create list of class objects and store the file data into it and bind that list to gridview. Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886945/reading-a-text-file-and-inserting-information-into-a-new-object and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020987/binding-list-to-gridview

Answer (score 0):

Input data into a DataTable.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Col A", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col B", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col C", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col D", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col E", typeof(string));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string inputLine = "";
            while((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] inputArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
                dt.Rows.Add(inputArray);
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```